# Script debugger not attaching in Razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following script block being rendered by a Razor view, but the `debugger` line is simply ignored, in Chrome; in Firebug it works as expected.  The `alert` is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function provinceChanged(e) {
        debugger;     
        var url = "/Address/ListCities";
        alert(url);
    }
</script>
```

Anyone have a suggestion why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have script debugging enabled in Internet Options? 
It's worth double-checking.

This has nothing to do with how your page was rendered...

Comment: I found and unchecked 2 'disable script debugging' options in Internet Options with no change.  The 'debugger' breakpoint keyword still has no effect.

Comment: Have you restarted the browsers?

Comment: You could also put a breakpoint in FireBug and see if it is hit.

Comment: the 'debugger' line now works in Firebug, I have edited the question, but I have even restarted my whole machine with no effect in Chrome.